# Replace null value with 'N' when there are no rows selected for the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to replace a column value with 'N' when it is null or there are no rows selected when the query is executed.Please see my query below:

```
Select case when ISNULL(myCol,'')='' then 'N' end as col
FROM myTable where <conditions>
```

If the result of the query is empty, I want `myCol` value to be 'N'. Please let me know if it is doable.

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL(myCol,'N') FROM myTable where <conditions>), 'N')
```

The inside `ISNULL` is used when a row is returned but its value is null, the external `ISNULL` is used if no rows are returned by your query

My trial:

```
CREATE TABLE #APP (ID VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #APP VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), (NULL)
```

This query will return **M** (because I take the only row with ID = NULL)

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL(ID,'M') FROM #APP WHERE ID IS NULL), 'N')
```

This query will return **N** (because I don't take any rows)

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL(ID,'M') FROM #APP WHERE ID = '100'), 'N')
```

Comment: No rows still. Empty result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ISNULL`'s 2nd parameter to replace null values with a different value, no need for the `case` statement:

```
Select ISNULL(myCol,'N') FROM myTable where <conditions>
```

To replace **blank** values (not `NULL` values):

```
SELECT myCol = COALESCE(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(myCol)), ''),'N') 
FROM myTable where <conditions>
```

Comment: Works for me, just tested it. What is the column type? Are you sure the values not replaces by `N` are `NULL`?

Comment: Column type is char

Comment: I've tested this several times, works. Are you 100% sure that you have null values? What are you getting exactly when you run this?

Comment: In char type, if there is no value, that would be taken as null right?

Comment: @Abhishek No! No value **does not** mean `NULL` Value! It simply means there is no value.

Comment: Oops!! so how should I handle this?

Comment: `Select case when myCol='' then 'N' end as col
FROM myTable where <conditions>`

Comment: Try: `COALESCE(NULLIF(myCol,''), 'N')`

Comment: Try: `SELECT myCol = COALESCE(NULLIF(myCol, ''),'N') FROM myTable where <conditions> `

Comment: Not even this one.

Comment: Perhaps the values are not blank? Maybe there are spaces?

Comment: Its like we do not get any row selected as result of a query. In such case, if I want to make a column value explicitly to something else , how can I do it is my question.

Comment: Try updating your blank values to null: `update myTable set myCol = NULL where LTRIM(RTRIM(myCol))=''`

Comment: And then use my 1st solution

Answer (score 0):

Union with a filler row which is excluded if the original query returns at least one row

```
select top(1) with ties col
from(
    -- original query 
    Select ISNULL(myCol,'N') as col
       , row_number() over (order by myCol) rn
       , 1 priority
    from myTable 
    where <conditions>
    -- a filler row
    UNION 
    select 'N' col, 1, 2  -- filler row with low priority
    ) t
order by row_number() over (partition by rn order by priority);
```

Comment: I'm not sure he only wants one result. I understood he wants all the results with nulls replaces with N or one result with N if empty result set is returned.

Comment: @hummingBird, yes, the query will return all the rows satisfying <conditions> if any exists or the filler row if no row satisfying the <conditions> exists.

Comment: didn't know that - guess I'm missing some syntax knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Joe Taras' (correct) answer:

```
if object_id ( 'tempdb..#APP' ) IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #APP

CREATE TABLE #APP (ID VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #APP VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), (NULL)

SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL(ID,'N') FROM #APP where ID = 1), 'N')
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL(ID,'N') FROM #APP where ID = 2), 'N')
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL(ID,'N') FROM #APP where ID = 3), 'N')
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL(ID,'N') FROM #APP where ID = 4), 'N')
```